# Change file's numbers Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename

I need to implement a script (duplq.sh) that would rename all the text files existing in the current directory using the command line arguments. So if the command `duplq.sh pic 0 3` was executed, it would do the following transformation:

`pic0.txt` will have to be renamed `pic3.txt`

`pic1.txt` to  `pic4.txt`

`pic2.txt` to  `pic5.txt`

`pic3.txt` to  `pic6.txt`

etc…

So the first argument is always the name of a file the second and the third always a positive digit.

I also need to make sure that when I execute my script, the first renaming (pic0.txt to pic3.txt), does not erase the existing pic3.txt file in the current directory.

Here's what i did so far :

```
 #!/bin/bash

name="$1"
i="$2"
j="$3"


for file in $name*
do
    echo $file
    find /var/log -name 'name[$i]' | sed -e 's/$i/$j/g'
    i=$(($i+1))
    j=$(($j+1))
done
```

But the find command does not seem to work. Do you have other solutions ?

Comment: Btw.: Paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution...

```
#!/bin/sh

NUMBERS=$(ls $1|sed -e 's/pic//g' -e 's/\.txt//g'|sort -n -r)

for N in $NUMBERS
do
    NEW=$(($N + 3))
    echo "pic$N.txt -> pic$NEW.txt"
    mv "pic$N.txt" "pic$NEW.txt"
done
```

Comment: In this case, you assume that the first digit in argument is zero and the second is 3. But it must work with any argument. Also, the second argument is not necessarily superior to the first, so the addition does not work.

Comment: ok, it was not so clear from the description you gave. now I got it :)

Comment: See [why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Similarly, [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). And the lack of quotes in `ls $1` also means this won't work if given a directory name with spaces.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy would you have a solution ?

Comment: If the question were better-specified I might, but it's not clear what the OP wants, and I have no interest in trying to guess at their intent.

Comment: Or do you mean a solution for the problems I pointed out? `shopt -s nullglob; files_by_number=( ); for file in pic*.txt; do num=${file//[![:digit:]]/}; files_by_number[$num]=$file; done` will give you an array mapping numbers to the filenames they were extracted from (without using `ls` or `sed`), so you can deal with the numbers independently of the names. Similarly, with an array, no need for string-splitting for iteration.

Comment: @Lino I have specified my question and still have not found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

`find` possible files, `sort` the names by number, use `sed` to remove files with lower numbers than `$1`, reverse `sort` by number, and start at the top renaming from the highest number down to the lowest:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$1"'[0-9]*' | 
sort -g | sed -n "/^$1$2."'/,$p' | sort -gr | 
while read x ; do
    p="${x%%[0-9]*.*}"; s="${x##*[0-9]}" ; i="${x%$s}" i="${i#$p}"
    mv "$x" "$p$((i+$3))$s"
done
```